# Launch Screen Background Image with iPhone 6, 6+, XS, XR, XS Max Support

Tags: ios, xcode10, launch-screen

Now, I'm new to set launch image of iPhone XR, XS, XS Max. But I want to set background image in `LaunchScreen` due to there are some requirement to add text and other images in `LaunchScreen`.

I'm able to set `LaunchImage` for splash screen, but due to requirement I must requires to use `LaunchScreen`.

Now, I'm confused in naming conversion with different sizes of background image which I have to add in `Bundle`.

So,

> How could I give name of images, So it will be dynamically set based on
>   screen resolution for all devices which are listed above ?

Anyone have idea! Then please help me.

Comment: You just use a single background image that is set to `scaleAspectFill`. Some of the image will bleed outside the visible area depending on the device screen size. Add the text with labels so that the font is clear.

Comment: @Paulw11, Thanks for suggestion. I could add max. size of image for it, but it will stretch and looks weird.

Comment: You need to ensure that your image is larger than the largest device (currently iPhone XS Max if you aren't targeting iPad) then it will scale down on smaller devices. Using "aspect fill" ensures that the aspect ratio is maintained so the image isn't distorted.

Comment: Okay, let me check it, will inform what happening.

Comment: @Paulw11, Your solution worked, you should add as Answer.